# Is deleting our gallery after having saved our photos in Google photos safe?

Tags: google, gallery, google-photos

I wanted to know if it was possible to delete our gallery after having saved all our photos in Google photos ? Will our photos be saved in like our Google account or something like that ? Or it will delete all our photos in our gallery and in Google photos ?

Answer (score 1):

**The purpose of google photos is never running out of storage on your phone. So if you backup your photos on google photos you put them in a cloud storage, you can access this cloud everywhere and everytime you want.
If you delete your gallery but you saved it before on google photos there is no problem, as i said before the purpose of this app is to gain internal storage on your phone**